# SQL - issue with join and not matching row

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I'm facing an issue trying to join 4 tables:

**Conversation:**

```
+-----+---------+------------+
| id: | start:  |    end:    |
+-----+---------+------------+
| a   |  3      |    87      |
| e   |  <null> |   4        |
| h   |  4      |    67      |
| l   |  5      |    6       |
| o   |  <null> |  <null>    |
+-----+---------+------------+
```

**Phone:**

```
+-----+-------------+--------+
| id: | P_duration: | T_id:  |
+-----+-------------+--------+
| a   | 2           | a1     |
| e   | <null>      | <null> |
| h   | 5           | <null> |
+-----+-------------+--------+
```

**Chat:**

```
+-----+--------------+---------+
| id: |  C_duration: |  T_id:  |
+-----+--------------+---------+
| l   |            4 |    a2   |
+-----+--------------+---------+
```

**Ticket**

```
+---------+
|    T_id |
+---------+
|    a1   |
|    a2   |
|    a3   |
+---------+
```

What I'm trying to obtain is something like this:

**Result:**

```
+--------+-------------+-------------+--------+
|  id:   | P_duration: | C_duration: | T_id:  |
+--------+-------------+-------------+--------+
| a      | 2           | <null>      | a1     |
| e      | <null>      | <null>      | <null> |
| h      | 5           | <null>      | <null> |
| l      | <null>      | 4           | a2     |
| o      | <null>      | <null>      | <null> |
| <null> | <null>      | <null>      | a3     |
+--------+-------------+-------------+--------+
```

I tried with a query like this

```
SELECT 
    conv.id, p.P_duration, c.C_duration, t.T_id
FROM 
    Conversations conv
LEFT JOIN 
    phone p ON p.id = conv.id
LEFT JOIN 
    chat c ON c.id = conv.id
LEFT JOIN 
    ticket t ON (t.T_id = p.T_id OR t.T_id = c.T_id)
```

Unfortunately this is not working since I can't cover the last row on the result table case: when I have a ticket but no conversation.

How should I change the query?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I am going to suggest `UNION ALL` to bring in the tickets that do not match the `phone` and `chat` tables:

```
SELECT conv.id, p.P_duration, c.C_duration, t.T_id
FROM Conversations conv LEFT JOIN
     phone p
     ON p.id = conv.id LEFT JOIN
     chat c 
     ON c.id = conv.id LEFT JOIN
     ticket t 
     ON t.T_id IN (p.T_id, c.T_id)
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, t.T_id
FROM ticket t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM phone p
                  WHERE t.T_id = p.T_id
                 ) AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM chat c
                  WHERE t.T_id = c.T_id
                 );
```

Comment: Thanks. This really work, but really slow. any idea on how to increase performance with this union all?

Comment: @Giacky . . . You want indexes on `phone(T_id)` and `chat(T_id)`.  That said, this should  not be much slower than your original query.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a FULL JOIN when joining to the ticket table.

```
select conv.id, p.P_duration, c.C_duration, t.T_id
FROM Conversations conv
LEFT JOIN phone p on p.id = conv.id
LEFT JOIN chat c on c.id = conv.id
FULL JOIN ticket t on (t.T_id= p.T_id or t.T_id= c.T_id)
```

Not sure about performance here. The UNION ALL approach may perform better.

Comment: FULL JOIN is not working, even if the performance with FULL JOIN are better than UNION ALL. But is working with union all. But really slow

Comment: I think my FULL JOIN criteria is incorrect. I have phone joining to itself. I'll fix that.

Comment: Thank you. i'll wait your solution with FULL JOIN

Comment: I fixed it when I made the earlier comment. If it still doesn't work I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: oh. get it. Unfortunately is not working with full join. I can't retrieve the rows that have conv.id, p.P_duration, c.C_duration null.